# bootstrap-select is used in multiple places in one page but only working for the first one

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, select, bootstrap-select

I have used three bootstrap-select (https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) in one page in my react component, I have followed all the instructions given, but only the first one is working properly and the other ones are not showing at all, here is the code snippet:

```
componentDidMount() { 
  $('.select').selectpicker();
  $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({ style: 'btn-info', size: 4 });
}

<div className="custom-select">
  <p className="font-300"> Drill Down Select </p>
  <select className="sidebar-select m-bot-1 selectpicker selectbg" onChange = {this.handleGraphTypeSelect.bind(this)}>
    <option selected disabled="disabled">Drill Downs</option>
    <option value="2_AXIS">Two axis graph</option>
    <option value="MULTIPLE_AXIS">Multiple axis</option>
    <option value="LOCATION">Location</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

the other two has the same classes and structures but different values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use different class selectors in JQuery will solve your current issues

like

```
$('.select').selectpicker(); $('.selectpicker').selectpicker({ style: 'btn-info', size: 4 });
$('.select1').selectpicker(); $('.selectpicker1').selectpicker({ style: 'btn-info', size: 4 });
$('.select2').selectpicker(); $('.selectpicker2').selectpicker({ style: 'btn-info', size: 4 });
```

Comment: could you please explain what is these .select1, .select2 is here? select is the tag used in the library so you can not use anything than select here otherwise the design breaks.

Comment: please can you help answering the question? @Abdul Hameed